# По локализации веб-приложения

Tags: javascript, html, i18n, локализация

Существует веб-приложение, делаю возможность выбора языков. Добавил в элементы, содержащие строки для перевода, класс `custom-lang`, а вместо строк условные лейблы (`[line1]`). Просто получаю потом список всех элементов и прогоняю циклом по всем сообщениям — если `атрибуты`, `.value` или `.textContent` содержат условный лейбл, заменяю его на строку. А в `<html>` впендюриваю `lang="code" dir="ltr/rtl"`.

Всё прекрасно работает, кроме случая, когда в строке находится ещё один элемент. Например, ссылка.

```
    <span class="custom-lang">[line1] <a class="custom-lang" href="[line2]">[line3]</a></span>
```

Разумеется, заменить в этом случае лейбл невозможно. Если сделать `.textContent = .textContent.replace()`, то заменится и ссылка. А если заключить строку в свой блок (`<span><span>Строка</span><a>ссылка</a></span>`), то при письменности справа-налево всё это превращается в кашу (ссылка оказывается спереди).

Да, можно просто заменить по тексту через `.replace()` на весь блок (или даже всю страницу), но проблема в том, что переведённые строки генерируют пользователи. И там может быть в теории что угодно, в том числе милая XSSочка. Это небезопасно.

Что в этом случае можно придумать? Желательно без монструозных библиотек для локализации, проблема только в этом.